# Principal key mapping to column of different name in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have quite a big database and I am building small app on top of it to manage a little portion of data.
The problem is that there is convention in database team where columns that are primary keys in the database are named `PK_EntityName`.

Now I do not want to bring that convention into C# code.

How do I map property `Id` of C# class to `PK_EntityName` column using fluent api?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#column-names

Comment: ```builder.Property(...)``` return object of type ```PropertyBuilder<T>```, for wich extention method ```HasColumnName()``` exists.

```builder.HasKey(...)``` _(which is used to specify principal key for entity)_ return object of type ```KeyBuilder```. And for that type you can not invoke ```HasColumnName()``` 

Comment: These have different  purpose (configure different things). `HasKey` is to tell which *property* of the object is the PK. Column name of the PK (or any other) *property* is configured through `Property(...).HasColumnName(...)`. i.e. you need `HasKey(e => e.Id)` (although it is redundant because property named `Id` is assumed PK by convention, so you can skip it) plus `Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("PK_EntityName")` :)

Comment: OOOOHHH!!!!!!! Sweeeeeet! Thank you a lot for enlightenment!!!